# Listview showing duplicate values on execution

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

When I try to load data from SQLite database to my `ListView` each item is duplicated.

I double checked my database values while getting to the `Cursor`: there is no redundant data in it. But when I try to show in `ListView` I get duplicate entries. I tried other questions from this section, but nothing can solve my problem. I know that hash set can reduce redundant data. But I have no idea about how to use it.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.distance);

     list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
     openAndQueryDatabase();
     displayResultList();

}

private void displayResultList() {

    String[] fromwhere = { "code","name" };
    int[] viewswhere = { R.id.id,R.id.name};
          ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(Distance.this, datas,
            R.layout.simple_list_row, fromwhere, viewswhere);
    list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
  list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {

       datas = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct cust_code,cust_name from customer", null);

    Log.v("detailss", c.toString());

        while (c.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String, String> datanums = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String custcode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cust_code"));
        datanums.put("code", custcode);
        datas.add(datanums);

        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cust_name"));
        datanums.put("name", name);

         datas.add(datanums);
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } 

}
```

Comment: Are there really two identical rows for each database row (= pair of code and name)?

Comment: @0X0nosugar  In database there is no duplication of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at how you transfer data from the `Cursor` 'c' to the `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` 'datas':

> ```
> while (c.moveToNext()){
>     HashMap<String, String> datanums = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     String custcode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cust_code"));
>     datanums.put("code", custcode);
>     datas.add(datanums);
>
>     String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cust_name"));
>     datanums.put("name", name);
>
>     datas.add(datanums);
> }
> ```

Each `Cursor` position belongs to one database table row. (If we think of query results as very short-lived tables this is even true for queries with JOIN etc.)

In your code, we see that for each row you add a `Map` to the `ArrayList` in two places.

- First, you put ("code", custcode) to the `Map` 'datanums' and add it to the `List`.
- Then you put ("name", name) to *the same object*, i.e. 'datanums'. *This means you changed the object which is already contained in the list.*
- You add this object to the `List` a second time. Now the `List` has pairs of identical elements and the `ListView` shows duplicate entries.

You need only one `List` element per row, so drop one of the `datas.add(datanums);` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much..It cleared my problem.And thanks for the detailed description, this will help me to keep it in mind when dealing with map.:)